# CakePHP: Cannot set a variable when calling an element

Tags: cakephp

I'm looping over a set of products like this

```
<?php foreach ($results as $result): ?>
   <?php echo $this->element('result_item', array('product', $result)); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and here's an excerpt of my element code:

```
[...]
<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'view', 'action' => 'index', $product['Product']['product_slug'])) ?>
[...]
```

I'm getting the following error each I try to access $product

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: product [APP/View/Elements/result_item.ctp, line 2]/view">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: pls add element and controller code for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing through two arguments, instead of one named argument.

Change your view code to be this:

```
<?php foreach ($results as $result): ?>
   <?php echo $this->element('result_item', array('product' => $result)); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

(Note the => instead of , in the element call)

Comment: I feel stupid now.. I'm gonna go with it was late.. :$  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use array to pass variables to element.

See doc here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#passing-variables-into-an-element